# Why dask throw IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 when I use apply_along_axis?

Tags: python, dask

I try to use `dask.array.apply_along_axis` to a 2D array. However, my array is a dask array, it always throws an exception which like following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/test/apply_along_axis_test.py", line 22, in <module>
    b = da.apply_along_axis(lambda  a: a[index_array], 1, source_array)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\dask\array\routines.py", line 383, in apply_along_axis
    test_result = np.array(func1d(test_data, *args, **kwargs))
  File "D:/test/apply_along_axis_test.py", line 22, in <lambda>
    b = da.apply_along_axis(lambda  a: a[index_array], 1, source_array)
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

However, when I apply this method to a `numpy.array`. It can run successfully.

An example code is like this:

```
source_array = np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 4))
index_array = np.asarray([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]])

b = np.apply_along_axis(lambda a: a[index_array], 1, source_array)
print(b)

source_array = da.from_array(source_array)
b = da.apply_along_axis(lambda  a: a[index_array], 1, source_array)
```

I can successfully print b. However, the last row of the code will throw the exception. I think maybe I should use some map method like `map_partitions`. However, I can not find any method like this in `dask.array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be resolved by defining `shape` and `dtype`.  You can either do this manually or use `make_meta` to infer what it should be:

```py
In [55]: from dask.dataframe.utils import make_meta

In [56]: da.apply_along_axis(lambda  a: a[index_array], 1, source_array,
    ...:                     shape=make_meta(source_array).shape,
    ...:                     dtype=make_meta(source_array).dtype).compute()
Out[56]:
array([[[2, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 1],
        [6, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [6, 1],
        [9, 6],
        [3, 9]]])
```

You are also not the first person to run into this issue: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3727

Comment: Thx, It works! The issue that you provide is exactly what I want!